# How to validate receipt in InApp purchase in Ionic1/Ionic2 app in ios?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to implement InApp purchase in ionic ios app.but, I can not able to validate the receipt.
I'm able to get transaction id and receipt after purchasing the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate inapp purchase, we need to post to the server the receipt key (base64 key) which you received after purchase, and from the server side it will be validated.

Comment: how to check whether the user has already purchased the product during app launch? How you are validating receipts in server side?